# JAVA JFrame reference error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, chess

I need a little help with my JAVA code. Basically I have to make a chessboard, so it has to be a JFrame, JPanel, 64 buttons in a grid layout (8 by 8) and put the 16 chess pieces image on the buttons.

Now here is the problem I have this working in one file but to make it harder, I have to split the code between two files. So the GUI (JPanel, JFrame) have to be in one file and the code for the buttons and images have to be in another file.

This is where I am struggling as I have split my code between the two files, I need to reference the class called ChessSquare in the file ChessBoard. But in my code for the buttons which is a for loop of 8, with another for loop of 8 and then they get added to the JFrame, but as there is no JFrame reference outside of the GUI file, so this prevents my code from working.

How do I reference the JFrame called 'a' in the second file for the buttons?

Comment: Pass the references between classes using either a constructor, getter, or setter method. You might have to use the **this** keyword to pass an instance of "yourself" to classes you create.

Comment: Create a JPanel with the JButtons and JLabel images in one class.  Instantiate the JPanel in your JFrame class.  See my article, [John Conway’s Game of Life in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=504), for an example of dividing the view into more than one class.

Answer (score 0):

Make it ***Static*** if it is not already to be able to access it outside without a refernce to the object. Simply use:

```
NameOfClass.Variable
```

Example of static JFrame:

```
public static JFrame frame;
```